# Why is the runtime for this code O(N^2) when using a linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, runtime, big-o

So, for data structures here is a piece of code we are supposed to find the runtime for:

```
public static int calc( List<Integer> lst )
      {

         int count = 0;
         int N = lst.size();

         for ( int i=0; i<N; i++)
         {
            if (lst.get(i) > 0)
               sum += lst.get(i);
            else
               sum += lst.get(i) * lst.get(i);
         }
         return sum;
      }
```

We are supposed to answer what the runtime would be if `lst` is a `LinkedList` vs an `ArrayList`. So for an array it is pretty easy, just O(N) because it loops through the list checking every element, and `lst.get(i)` is a constant time operation since it is an array. The tricky part is over a linked list. From what I'm seeing, every time `lst.get(i)` would be called on a linked list, it would have to start at the head of the list and traverse to index i. And from this code it looks like it would call get either 3 times or 2 times depending on the result of the if statement, so I would think it would be O(N^4) / O(N^3) runtime. However, according to a grad student, it is O(N^2) time. Just wondering if someone can explain what the correct answer is and why.

I ran some test code on java and got this as my time result:
list 1 is elements 0 - 99 of size 100. And list 2 is elements 0 - 9999, of size 10,000
List one finished in 2868 ms, list two finished in 99443 ms.

Comment: `get(i)` is _O(n)_, Worst case is that code calls `get(i)` 3 times in the loop, so with the loop, worst case is _O(n * 3 * n)_, which is _O(n * n)_, which is _O(n²)_. --- Note that calling `get(i)` 3 times doesn't mean _n * n * n_, it means _n + n + n_, aka _3 * n_.

Comment: There are at worst 3 get operations for every loop iteration. For `LinkedList`, a get operation is `O(N)` because you have to walk the list. As such, there `3 * O(N)` operations, `N` times. Hence, `O(N^2)`.

Comment: Ohhh oh my gosh thank you guys so much. I was getting the O(N^3) mixed up with a simple 3*O(N). Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

There are at worst 3 get operations for every loop iteration. For `LinkedList`, a get operation is `O(N)` because you have to walk the list. As such, there at worst `3 * O(N)` operations, at worst `N` times. Hence, `O(N^2)`.

However, it can be made as efficient for `LinkedList` as `ArrayList` - and simpler - by using an enhanced for loop:

```
for (int e : lst) {
  if (e > 0)
    sum += e;
  else
    sum += e * e;
}
```

This internally uses an `Iterator`, which isn't `O(N)` to look up each element for `LinkedList`, because it keeps track of where it is: getting the next element from the `Iterator` is just `O(1)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the clarification.